# how to find a number which is present in an array or not and get the position of that number in java

Tags: java

I have tried with the below code. Please help me to get the output.
I want simple code that I can understand.

Suppose that number is 40:

```
public class PositionofElementinArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int value = 40;
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if(arr[i]==value){
            System.out.print(arr[i]);            
    }
        else{

        System.out.print("no element found");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't have the `else` inside the loop. Otherwise it will print "no element found" for every element that is not the target. You should `return` inside the `if` clause after printing the value to stop the loop, and print "no element found" after the loop finishes.

Comment: You're missing an opening brace for the `for` loop.

Comment: Please be sure to read compiler errors carefully. Once your code compiles, be sure to step through it with a debugger to make sure that each line is doing what you expect it to. Please see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: import java.util.Arrays;
  public class PositionofElementinArray {
    public static void main (String[] args) 
       {
           int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
           int value = 40;
           for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
           {
               if(arr[i]==value){
               System.out.print("value is "+arr[i]+" position is "+i);           
               }  
               
           }
           else{ Here I am getting syntax error for using else statement why.???
      
           System.out.print("no element found");
                  }}}

Comment: for using else statement after for loop I am getting syntax error. I want to use else to print " No element found ".

Answer (score 0):

`if(arr[i]==value)` here you are checking the value.
And `i` is the index/position

Comment: This is correct. Just checking if the value at that position in the array is equal to the value he's looking for.

Answer (score -1):

This code will print the value and its position.according to your example value is 40 position is 3.

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        int value = 40;
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==value){
            System.out.print("value is"+arr[i]+" "position is"+i);            
            }      
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This code will print the value and its position.according to your example value is 40 position is 3.

Comment: Please do remember you can edit your own post no matter what reputation level you have. You should add your further explainations by clicking the edit link above, instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: import java.util.Arrays; public class PositionofElementinArray { public static void main (String[] args) { int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}; int value = 40; for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) { if(arr[i]==value){ System.out.print("value is "+arr[i]+" position is "+i); } } else{ Here I am getting syntax error for using else statement why.??? System.out.print("no element found"); }}}

Comment: For using else statement after for loop I am getting syntax error. I want to use else to print " No element found "

Comment: @Afsar Alam,You should write else part within for loop as else part should be written after if..what mistake you're doing is writing else part after for loop condition